# How to plot and compare data at several time points over the entire time frame?

Tags: r

I have a limited background working with R, so your help is very much appreciated!
I ran an experiment where I have three treatment conditions (condition assumed to be stable over time).

I have environmental data such as Temp. and light intensity (all numerical) at three time points for the experimental replicates in each treatment. I have initial middle and final condition measurements. like, I have many readings/samples at each of the three time points for each treatment.

I want to plot this over the entire time frame from initial to end, not just the three time points I have, I guess there is some bootstrapping that needs to be done here, no?. I want to show that the conditions were stable over time (hopefully) and they are similar between treatments.
Any recommendation on how to approach this, please?

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds more like a theoretical question for https://stats.stackexchange.com as there are probably many different ways to fit curves/lines/ranges through points and extrapolate to the whole time series. Once you've decided on a particular strategy, then it's easier to get help about implementing it in code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach this, I'm still looking...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.